# Python install mitmproxy module on Windows build error - how to solve?

Tags: python, module, installation

```
E:\mitmproxy-0.7>    C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install
```

produces

```
error: file 'E:\mitmproxy-0.7\mitmproxy' does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: well, the obvious question is: does `E:\mitmproxy-0.7\mitmproxy` actually exist?

Comment: no, why should it? I just extracted the files from the mitmproxy.tar.gz. If I add this directory I get: "permission denied"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract all files from the [tarball](http://mitmproxy.org/download/mitmproxy-0.7.tar.gz), not only `setup.py`. `setup.py` is **not** a full-fledged installer (like a msi or exe file); it just contains instructions on how to build the other files in the tarball.

Comment: I did: I get the mitmproxy-0.7 direcotory and this has:  Verzeichnis von C:\Python27\mitmproxy-0.7

01.03.2012  17:50    <DIR>          .
01.03.2012  17:50    <DIR>          ..
01.03.2012  17:49    <DIR>          build
01.03.2012  17:49    <DIR>          doc
01.03.2012  17:49    <DIR>          examples
01.03.2012  17:49    <DIR>          libmproxy
25.02.2012  01:30             2.219 README.txt
25.02.2012  01:23             3.268 setup.py
01.03.2012  17:49    <DIR>          test
               2 Datei(en),          5.487 Bytes
               7 Verzeichnis(se), 17.228.279.808 Bytes frei